# Mongodb aggregation in inside a array

Tags: mongodb, aggregate-functions

I have the below mongo collection structure

```
    {
   "_id":"some mongo Id",
   "email":"user@user.in",
   "Course1":[
      {
         "sublesson":1,
         "timespent":10,
         "timestamp":"123456"
      },
      {
         "sublesson":1,
         "timespent":20,
         "timestamp":"123457"
      },
      {
         "sublesson":2,
         "timespent":20,
         "timestamp":"123458"
      }
   ]
}
```

Now, all need is to find the sum of time taken for each sublesson aggregated. I have tried some methods but cannot access the data inside the "course1" array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I can understand the requirement correctly you need to sum up the `timespent`.

Please give this a try:

```
db.testing.aggregate(
[
    {
        "$unwind":"$Course1"
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$email", 
            "timespent":
            {
                "$sum":"$Course1.timespent"
            }
        }
    }
]
);
```